# onChange swift to update variables, loop forever

Tags: swift, date, swiftui, logic

I'm stuck on the following issue, I have created 2 text field in an Hstack where the user can insert the local time in the format of HH:mm and it is converted automatically in UTC time in the second textfield and vice-versa.
TO do so I used onchange method, when the variable "localTime" changes, it updates the variable "utcTime" and vice-versa, but when I run the code it enters in an infinite loop because they keep updating each other... any solution how to avoid this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimeView: View {
    @Binding var localDate : Date?
    @Binding var utcDate : Date?
    
    /// continete l'ora in formato HH:mm
    @Binding var localTime : String
    @Binding var utcTime : String
    
    @Binding var selectedDate: Date
    
    @State var shouldUpdateUTCTime = true
    @State var shouldUpdateLocalTime = true
   
    let dateTimeFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        return formatter
    }()
    
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TimeTextField(time: $localTime, description: "Local Time")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                .onChange(of: localTime) { oldValue, newValue in
                    if shouldUpdateUTCTime {
                        updateUTCTime()
                    }
                }
                
            
            TimeTextField(time: $utcTime, description: "UTC")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                .onChange(of: utcTime) { oldValue, newValue in
                      if shouldUpdateLocalTime {
                        updateLocalTime()
                    }
                  
                }
                
        }
    }
    
    func updateUTCTime() {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        if let utcDate = dateFormatter.date(from: localTime) {
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC") // convert to utc the local
            let utcDateString = dateTimeFormatter.string(from: utcDate)
            utcTime = utcDateString
        }
    }
    func updateLocalTime() {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        if let local = dateFormatter.date(from: utcTime) {
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current // convert to current the local
            let localDateString = dateTimeFormatter.string(from: local)
            localTime = localDateString
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `if shouldUpdateUTCTime`, this will never work when you never change the property. Add some simple logic to set and reset the properties in each onChange

Comment: Your code is not enough to debug it, anyway I understand the problem. You can use @focusState, create a Hashable enum with two cases 1. UTC 2. local, and set focusState for each textField, now onChange check which focusState is current either UTC or Local based which is not active update that not active one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enum Field: Hashable {
    case universalTime
    case localTime
}

@FocusState var focusedState: Field?
```

Use focusState, add focused modifiers to each of textFields like this:

```
TextField("", text: $localTime)
     .focused($focusedState, equals: .localTime)

TextField("", text: $universalTime)
     .focused($focusedState, equals: .universalTime)
```

and than .onChange modifier check focusState and call the methods based on current / active focusState,

For LocalTime TextField:

```
.onChange(of: localTime) { _ in
  if focusedState == .localTime {
      updateUTCTime()
     }
  }
```

For UniversalTime TextField:

```
.onChange(of: universalTime) { _ in
   if focusedState == .universalTime {
       updateLocalTime()
     }
   }
```

Now it will not go into infinite loop.

Comment: fantastic works as i want, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like a boolean for is setting other? Set it to true when onChange of one is and false in onChange of other and react to set only if it is false. I think like two booleans, one set to true and one set to false in each function set time for other. That set to true should only be if setting other so like if not boolean then set setting other to true and set other.

After that setting this boolean set to false. Variables should be global, those two booleans, and accessible to both functions. Order of operations should be if !(other setting this) then set setting other to true then set other, after all that, other setting this in function set to false. I do not see where you set these variables, booleans, you just have them.

### Update

Since that did not work, you could try in setter method for other check if other is already correct before setting.

Comment: actually, i have try many options using some variables but i can't find the solution with the right logic, see my updated code